# tmap only plotting first polygon in sf geometry column

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

tmap is only plotting the first polygon in an sf geometry column, but `plot()` gets them all.

Some github issues for [tmap](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/360) and [leaflet](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/631) mention something similar, but they were related to names in an sf geometry column (which the World data doesn't have). Additionally, the problem was fixed in both packages.

Here's a reprex using the first example in the [tmap Getting Started vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html).

```r
library(tmap)
#> Warning: package 'tmap' was built under R version 3.5.3
data("World")

# tmap only plots one polygon
tm_shape(World) +
    tm_polygons("HPI")
```

[image]

```r
# plot gets them all
plot(World["HPI"])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United States.1252  
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252  
#>  tz       America/Chicago             
#>  date     2020-10-15                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package      * version  date       lib source        
#>  abind          1.4-5    2016-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  assertthat     0.2.1    2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  backports      1.1.10   2020-09-15 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  base64enc      0.1-3    2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  callr          3.5.1    2020-10-13 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.1)
#>  class          7.3-14   2015-08-30 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  classInt       0.4-3    2020-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  cli            2.1.0    2020-10-12 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.1)
#>  codetools      0.2-15   2016-10-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  crayon         1.3.4    2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  crosstalk      1.1.0.1  2020-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  curl           4.3      2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  DBI            1.1.0    2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  desc           1.2.0    2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  devtools       2.3.2    2020-09-18 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  dichromat      2.0-0    2013-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  digest         0.6.25   2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  dplyr          1.0.2    2020-08-18 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  e1071          1.7-3    2019-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  ellipsis       0.3.1    2020-05-15 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  evaluate       0.14     2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  fansi          0.4.1    2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  fs             1.5.0    2020-07-31 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  generics       0.0.2    2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  glue           1.4.2    2020-08-27 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  highr          0.8      2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  htmltools      0.5.0    2020-06-16 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  htmlwidgets    1.5.2    2020-10-03 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  httr           1.4.2    2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  KernSmooth     2.23-15  2015-06-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  knitr          1.30     2020-09-22 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  lattice        0.20-35  2017-03-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  leafem         0.1.3    2020-07-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  leaflet        2.0.3    2019-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  leafsync       0.1.0    2019-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  lifecycle      0.2.0    2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  lwgeom         0.2-5    2020-06-12 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  magrittr       1.5      2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  memoise        1.1.0    2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  mime           0.9      2020-02-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  pillar         1.4.6    2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  pkgbuild       1.1.0    2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  pkgconfig      2.0.3    2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  pkgload        1.1.0    2020-05-29 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  png            0.1-7    2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  prettyunits    1.1.1    2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  processx       3.4.4    2020-09-03 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  ps             1.3.4    2020-08-11 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  purrr          0.3.4    2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  R6             2.4.1    2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  raster         3.3-13   2020-07-17 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  RColorBrewer   1.1-2    2014-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  Rcpp           1.0.5    2020-07-06 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  remotes        2.2.0    2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  rlang          0.4.7    2020-07-09 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  rmarkdown      2.4      2020-09-30 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  rprojroot      1.3-2    2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  sessioninfo    1.1.1    2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  sf             0.9-6    2020-09-13 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  sp             1.4-2    2020-05-20 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  stars          0.4-3    2020-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  stringi        1.5.3    2020-09-09 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  stringr        1.4.0    2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  testthat       2.3.2    2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  tibble         3.0.3    2020-07-10 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  tidyselect     1.1.0    2020-05-11 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  tmap         * 3.2      2020-09-15 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  tmaptools      3.1      2020-07-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  units          0.6-7    2020-06-13 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  usethis        1.6.3    2020-09-17 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  vctrs          0.3.4    2020-08-29 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  viridisLite    0.3.0    2018-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  withr          2.3.0    2020-09-22 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  xfun           0.18     2020-09-29 [1] RSPM (R 3.5.3)
#>  XML            3.99-0.3 2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  xml2           1.3.2    2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  yaml           2.2.1    2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#> 
#> [1] C:/R_packages
#> [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library
```

Comment: Hi! I cannot reproduce your results using R 3.6.3 and tmap 3.2, can you try updating your R version?

Comment: Hello - I'll have to do some corporate IT wrangling, but hopefully that will fix it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem. So, I upgraded to the recent version of the tmap package and R version. The problem was fixed.

R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Tmap package version 3.3-1