# R tmap: polygons plotted in tmap_mode("view") but with ("plot") only the first observation

Tags: r, plot, view, polygon, tmap

I am trying to plot a polygon with `tmap`  r package.

My object comes from a shapefile, and looks like:

```
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 453850.6 ymin: 7168979 xmax: 513813.6 ymax: 7234603
CRS:            +proj=utm +zone=36 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
First 10 features:
   NeighCode  NameNeigh   Locality AdminPost Populacao Shape_Leng Shape_Area                       geometry
1       3914    Bassane Chichongue   Calanga       114  41926.454  111037471 POLYGON ((504325.3 7212444,...
2       3913 Chinguwine Chichongue   Calanga       181  16966.423   14526253 POLYGON ((499974.9 7212379,...
3       3912   Sihanine Chichongue   Calanga       238  13508.601    9502638 POLYGON ((500542.6 7208832,...
4       3911    Mpalene Chichongue   Calanga       352   6961.326    2646152 POLYGON ((499063.9 7208412,...
5       3910 Chichongue Chichongue   Calanga       342  12096.768    6473003 POLYGON ((498551.8 7206144,...
```

When I am trying to plot it with `plot()`, I get this:

[image]

But, when I am doing it with `tmap` with the following code:

```
dss_map <- tm_shape(dss_utm) + 
  tm_polygons("AdminPost") + 
  tm_layout(frame = F)
dss_map
```

I get the following map with `tmap_mode("plot")`.

[image]
Only the first observation is plotted. With `tmap_mode("view")` all of them are plotted.

Anyone could tell me what is happening? I could plot this object in `tmap_mode("plot")` before without any problems. Here is a link ([tmap only plotting first polygon in sf geometry column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380204/tmap-only-plotting-first-polygon-in-sf-geometry-column/66007622?noredirect=1#comment116705656_66007622/)) of a similar question that wasn't answered.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What versions of R and `tmap` are you using (`packageVersion("tmap")` will say). Does it happen if you use, for example, the `nc` data read in with `example(st_read)` and then mapped with: `tm_shape(nc) + tm_polygons("NAME") + tm_layout(frame=F)` because structurally that looks identical to your code but works fine for me. Does it for you?

Comment: Please embed images in your question instead of linking to them. You can use the image button above the editor (it is just right of the {} button).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380204/tmap-only-plotting-first-polygon-in-sf-geometry-column/67680558#67680558 FIXED!

Comment: Fixed over there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380204/tmap-only-plotting-first-polygon-in-sf-geometry-column